# How can I create webform preview page where user can go next to submit or edit?

Tags: forms, nodes, webforms

I am trying to figure our what opportunities webform module provides for previewing forms after entering data and editing them by users before submission. I read module code, but did not find anywhere in it even how webform defines its node type. Please help!